# What does "epitragic" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

From a paper by Anthony Baker titled "[“for the murder of his own female slave, a woman named Mira...” : Law, Slavery and Incoherence in Antebellum North Carolina](https://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1017&context=student_papers)":

> Apart from its gripping melodrama and **epitragic** conclusion, the case of The State of North Carolina v. John Hoover would not appear to commend any appreciable attention from legal historians seeking to trace the potent interface of law and society, on first, quick reading.

What is the meaning of **epitragic** here? Since "epi" means "upon", could it mean "**finally, tragic** conclusion" ("tragic-in-the-final-end")?

I came across the word reading this [topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/52650/3085) on History SE.

Of course I did look for it in a dictionary, and found it not.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: @ James K , have *you* found it in a dictionary? I looked Merriam Webster, & did not find. Searched on it and didn't even find any (other) coherent English text containing it. Personally I think it is a made-up word, but can we be understanding when a learner can't figure out what it means?

Comment: @LorelC. Well, this is sort of the point.  Has the OP checked a dictionary?  If the answer is yes, then all well and good. They won't find it. I know that because I have checked. But this kind of research needs to be done first. *All* words are made up words. The quoted text is quite coherent and there are four of five more examples.

Comment: "Upon" is not the only meaning of [the prefix "epi"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/epi-). I think that here, "epitragic"  could mean either/both "more than tragic".or/and "nearly tragic".

Comment: @JamesK - of course I did, and found it not.

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours. As James says, it is not in the dictionary (at least not in the on-line ones). As far as I'm aware, there is no established use of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This word doesn't appear in dictionaries, which means it has very little currency. There is a few uses on the web, in which it seems to be being used synonymously with "melodramatic":

> There had been a time when [women] were romantic ideals, to be sung about in epitragic ballads.
>
> Or, as the rest of the world knows this horrendous, sensational, epitragic story... "Just another day in floriduh."
>
> The violence [...] was not an *hamartia* of epi-tragic proportions but a necessary transgression that paved the way for the divine cycle of the first birth.

The word could have been coined independently several times, either from epi+tragic (beyond tragedy), or as a portmanteau of "epic tragedy"

Answer (score 2):

I found for this word at least 4 forms: **epitragic** as you noted, as well as **epi-tragic**, **epictragic**, and **epic-tragic** (which is the most common form among the mentioned forms).

Anyway, this term is a literary term which means to combine or bind between two opposite terms "**epic**" and "**tragic**" ([see here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=bmi4EUKzLtQC&pg=PA139&dq=%22epic%20tragic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjds-b2iKfiAhVxlIsKHY8CCw0Q6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22epic%20tragic%22&f=false), also [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=bmi4EUKzLtQC&pg=PA139&dq=%22epic%20tragic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjds-b2iKfiAhVxlIsKHY8CCw0Q6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22epic%20tragic%22&f=false) for example).